# Best way to add package's models path to GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH in ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, package.xml, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS1, you could add your package's `models` path to the `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` in `package.xml` (e.g. [as shown here](https://github.com/sloretz/gazebo_model_path_example/blob/457fdcb01831a3045f95be8ea0f43bee31fc791e/gazebo_model_path_example/package.xml#L14-L17)).

It doesn't seem like the same functionality (provided by [gazebo_ros_paths_plugin.cpp](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_paths_plugin.cpp)) exists in ROS2. So is there a preferred alternative?

I know you can set environment variables [using launch substitutions](https://answers.ros.org/question/343220/ros2-extend-env-vars-in-launch-file-instead-of-overwriting/), but this would have to be done for each launch file.

Is there a way to set the environment variable at the package level (or at the workspace level, e.g. when sourcing your `setup.bash`)? Or would that be bad form?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380288/best-way-to-add-package%27s-models-path-to-gazebo_model_path-in-ros2?/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1567 on 2021-06-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see it in the ros2 branch: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/84a088be9bfcba4f8dda29eb52265c112dd808d2/gazebo_ros/scripts/gazebo_ros_paths.py and I do believe it is working.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-06-15**:
One day I'll learn to look at the full directory, and to not just check if one particular file still exists... Thanks though - exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to add, another (and in my opinion cleaner) way to do it is using [environment hooks](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-Gazebo-ROS-Paths#env-hooks). This will set it directly in Gazebo (when you source the workspace), without the dependency on gazebo_ros.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2021-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2